# Is it worth re-doing RTK, or should I just learn Kanji through reading (and forget writing all together)?

Tags: discussion, kanji

I learnt the 常用漢字 last year (approx. 2200) via RTK, but due to work commitments, I lapsed on my revision and have essentially forgotten most of my Anki cards.

Is it worth re-doing them, or would I be better served simply learning Kanji through reading and forgoing writing essentially all together?

Comment: This is one of the reasons I dislike RTK method.

Comment: just IMO but RTK is a waste of time. Just memorize words, not kanji.

Comment: I did RTK as well and just like you, I slacked on my reviews and pretty much forgot the whole thing. Or rather I forgot the "English word - kanji" thing that the book teaches. What stayed with me was the approximate meaning of the characters though so I definitely wouldn't say it was a waste of time like some people here. It teaches how to look at the characters, what the individual coponents mean etc. If you still remember some of that, I'd say don't redo RTK and just do other stuff. Preferably a lot of reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get closed/migrated, since the site is for Japanese questions, not Japanese learning questions. But...

I think you'd be best served to pickup a vocab book or native texts, rather than redoing RTK.

The author of RTK states that it's purpose is to give your brain cubbies to put other bits of information into while it forms a web of connection (character-sound-meaning).  Even if you have lapsed on reviews, your brain still has the cubbies.  So start feeding it new info to start making connections.